# Writing to mysql table multiple lines one by one from nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a nodeJS code writing to a table in mysql. The process is long as it requires writing about 1 mn entries. So it is time consuming. What I want is to make the records that are being sent to mysql available for query as they committed to the database one by one. However, my the code appear to be collecting all records before committing then to the database. So I can not query database as the code is being executed. How can I change this? I need a situation where the code commits an entry to the database and this entry becomes available in the database for queries from external sources (say mysql workbench).

```
"use strict";

const mysql = require("mysql");

// Create connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "somePassword",
  database: "tickers"
});

// Connect
db.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("MySQL connected");


  for (var uniqueSets = 0; uniqueSets < 1000000; uniqueSets++) {

    // some programming logic here

    // then calling the procedure to commit data to mysql>>>
    sendToMYSQL(
      t1,
      t2,
      t3
    );
  }


function sendToMYSQL(t1, t2, t3) {
  let post = {
    t1: t1,
    t2: t2,
    t3: t3
  };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO scope SET?";
  let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks its trying to commit but, your mysql table is busy inserting these records. Set timeout for this for-loop.

```
var interval = 50; //milliseconds;

for (var uniqueSets = 0; uniqueSets < 1000000; uniqueSets++) {
    setTimeout(function (uniqueSets) {
        // some programming logic here

        // then calling the procedure to commit data to mysql>>>
        sendToMYSQL(
            t1,
            t2,
            t3
        );
    }, interval * uniqueSets, uniqueSets);
}
```

**Note**: uniqueSets is multiplied to interval to make sure the call timings are in sync based on the interval.

Answer (score 1):

My investigation finaly yielded a workable solution for the problem. The problem arises from mysql module setup, I believe. It appears that db.query does not commit data to server if the process that called it is not finished. I tried pretty much everything I could think ofincluding promises, async, await, process.nextTick(), different structures of code and etc. But the only thing that finaly worked for me was the following.  I replaced the for () iteration, which makes calculations and then calls sendToMYSQL with a new function which contans the programing logic for calculations. I introduced a global counter for the number of times this new function is called. I call the function once at the begining of code. Then in the sendToMYSQL I increment the counter if is below the targeted number of calculations and call new function again. As a result sendToMYSQL started to commit data to server as it receives it and this data became available for server queries from external programs. The solution does increase the time length of the process, but I am glad the solution was found. here is the code:

```
    "use strict";

const mysql = require("mysql");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "somePassword",
  database: "tickers"
});

db.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("MySQL connected");
})


var uniqueSets = 0 // this is the global counter
execute();

function execute() {

  // some calculations using uniqueSets as a pointer to some array

  sendToMYSQL(
    t1,
    t2,
    t3
  );
}


function sendToMYSQL(t1, t2, t3) {
  let post = {
    t1: t1,
    t2: t2,
    t3: t3
  };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO scope SET?";
  let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    if (uniqueSets < 100000) {
      uniqueSets++;
      execute()
    } else {
      console.log('finished');
      db.end();
    }
  });
}
```